# Why is there animating bug when tweet requests are called in iOS5?

Tags: twitter, ios5

The screen becomes blurred like UIAlertview is popping very slowly, whenever my app posts tweet requests in iOS5. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after the completion of request I used [alertView show] method in the the request handler block of TWRequest which I assume was called in different thread and was causing the issue. Calling that method in main thread solved the problem.

[alertView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];